# PHP: Convert variable to array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to convert a variable to an array and split each character using PHP.

So say I have a variable `$name = 'John Smith';` How do I convert it to:

```
array('J','o','h','n',' ','S','m','i','t','h');
```

Notice the space between John and Smith as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you need this? If you only need to access individual characters, you can just use [] on the string itself. E.g. `$name[1]` will get you `o`.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen, this method is not good for non-english letters (russian, for example).

Comment: @Kirzilla: That would've been a good thing to mention in your post, since many of the built-in functions don't support multibyte characters either. The multibyte string extension might help you, but I avoid PHP altogether due to its abysmal string handling.

Comment: @Kirzilla: I'm curious now, what happens with non-Latin alphabets?

Comment: @Matti: this isn't Kirzillas post, we don't know what chad needs...

Comment: @oezi: Oh, well spotted. The comment sounded like something only the OP would add so I didn't look at the names properly...

Comment: @Matti I'm using this to plot Characters in an image using imagettftext() I want to get the spacing perfect, so I want to plot each individual character separately.

Comment: @Chad: In that case, what I posted should be just the thing you need.

Answer (score 13):

There's [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split) for that.

Comment: +1 i'd suggested the explode function but of course, that requires a delimeter.

Answer (score 5):

You already can access your string using `[]` operator.

For example :

```
$var = "bonjour";
echo $var[0];
> 'b'
```

You then just have to use explode.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = "John Smith";

$arr = str_split($str);
```

**note:** maybe you don't have to do this, you can simply use a string like it's an array to get every character (`$str[1]` to get an 'o')

Answer (score 1):

`$array = preg_split('//', $string);`

However, you can treat strings as character arrays in php.

```
$string = 'foobar';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); ++$i) echo $string[$i];
```

Answer (score -1):

Chad,

try using the php 'explode' function
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

jim

Comment: Chad - Artefacto's suggestion is the best bet!!

Comment: I wouldn't use w3schools, nor I would use `explode()`.

Comment: truth, in truth neither would I :). thanks for being courteous enough to leave a reason for the -1. all the best..

Comment: I wasn't the one who DV'd you.